# Website on mobile not functioning the same as when viewed on the browser at the smallest screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, typo3, base-url

A client recently asked us to create a microsite that had the exact same look, feel and functionality as one of their current sites. Naturally, I ripped all the code, added a few bespoke classes etc, nothing big. Linked all the css and js within the site, and, once live on the staging server, it all looked great!

But then I looked at it on mobile, and it doesn't function properly. I find this strange as the site functions fine when the browser size is reduced to the minimum width. The site's live here: http://quantummarketing-group.com/Clients/Fujitsu/

I was able to find the source of my problem:

```
<script>
var NELibs = {};
NELibs.baseurl = "http://reshaping-datacenter.ts.fujitsu.com/";
NELibs.langid = "0";
NELibs.langkey = "en";
NELibs.langkey_alt = "";
NELibs.pageid = "9";
</script>
```

When I remove this code, the site displays on mobiles fine, just without the fancy JS effects, otherwise the site just does not function!

Now I can't understand why this code does not matter at all for the desktop version, but does on mobile. The code that references NELibs is here: http://quantummarketing-group.com/Clients/Fujitsu/js/bottomjquery.js (I tried absolutely referencing the links in that js file but there are some where that just won't cut it).

The original website was built using TYPO3 if that helps.

Let me know if you need anything else??

Comment: What if you put that script inside a $( document ).ready(function() {}); and move it to the bottom below where you reference bottomjquery.js? Also, you put jquery-mobile as a tag on the question but it does not appear that you are using the jquery-mobile library...

Comment: Sorry about the tag - I assumed there might be some link there! Thanks for the suggestion but it's still not working on mobiles - I think I might be missing some files from the TYPO3 structure so have asked for them. Don't understand how it works fine on a DT regardless though